# Allow access to S3 Bucket from all EC2 instances of specific Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Is there any way to allow all instances created by a specific AWS account access to an S3 bucket?

I would like to provide data that should be very simple for clients to download to their instances. Ideally, automatically via the `post_install` script option of [AWS ParallelCluster](https://github.com/aws/aws-parallelcluster).

However, it seems like this requires a lot of setup, as is described in this tutorial by AWS:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-instance-access-bucket/

This is not feasible for me. Clients should not have to create IAM roles.

The best I came up with at the moment is allowing S3 bucket access to a specific AWS account and then working with access keys:

```sh
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<key-id>
export AWS_SECRETE_ACCESS_KEY=<secret-key>

aws s3 cp s3://<bucket> . --recursive
```

Unfortunately, this is also not ideal as I would like to provide ready-to-use AWS Parallelcluster `post_install` scripts. These scripts should automatically download the required data on cluster startup.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to allow all instances created by a specific AWS account access to an S3 bucket?

Yes. It's a 2 step process. In summary:
1) On your side, the bucket must trust the account id of the other accounts that will access it, and you must decide which calls you will allow.
2) On the other accounts that will access the bucket, the instances must be authorised to run AWS API calls on your bucket using IAM policies.

In more detail:

**Step 1:** let's work through this and break it down.
On your bucket, you'll need to configure a bucket policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "111",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID_TO_TRUST:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can find more examples of bucket policies in the [AWS documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

**WARNING 1:** "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:root" will trust everything that has permissions to connect to your bucket on the other AWS account. This shouldn't be a problem for what you're trying to do, but it's best you completely understand how this policy works to prevent any accidents.

**WARNING 2:** Do not grant `s3:*` - you will need to scope down the permissions to actions such as `s3:GetObject` etc. There is a website to help you generate these policies [here](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html). `s3:*` will contain `delete` permissions which if used incorrectly could result in nasty surprises.

Now, once that's done, great work - that's things on your end covered.

**Step 2:** The other accounts that want to read the data will have to assign an instance role to the ec2 instances they launch and that role will need a policy attached to it granting access to your bucket. Those instances can then run AWS CLI commands on your bucket, provided your bucket policy authorises the call on your side and the instance policy authorises the call on their side.
The policy that needs to be attached to the instance role should look something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Keep in mind, just because this policy grants `s3:*` it doesn't mean they can do anything on your bucket, not unless you have `s3:*` in your bucket policy. Actions of this policy will be limited to whatever you've scoped the permissions to in your bucket policy.

> This is not feasible for me. Clients should not have to create IAM roles.

If they have an AWS account it's up to them on how they choose to access the bucket as long as you define a bucket policy that trusts their account the rest is on them. They can create an ec2 instance role and grant it permissions to your bucket, or an IAM User and grant it access to your bucket. It doesn't matter.

> The best I came up with at the moment is allowing S3 bucket access to a specific AWS account and then working with access keys:

If the code will run on an ec2 instance, it's bad practice to use access keys and instead should use an ec2 instance role.

> Ideally, automatically via CloudFormation on instance startup.

I think you mean via [instance userdata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html), which you can define through CloudFormation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer (+1). However, it is still not really what I  need. I changed my question to contain more information about my specific use case with AWS ParallelCluster. Clients create their EC2 instances via pcluster and they should only have to do as little configuration as possible. I would like to provide a post-install script that automatically downloads the required data.

Comment: I don't have much context on AWS ParallelCluster but the only advice I can give in this case is if any of the compute resources created by ParallelCluster can have an IAM role attached to them, you'd have to follow the same instructions above and attach the policy to the role. Whatever you decide to do, as long as it's in AWS, you should not be hardcoding access keys into any of resources created. That's all I can help out with here so I'll leave you to it. Good luck on your quest :)

Comment: It is possible to attach IAM roles to ParallelCluster instances. Still, I would have liked to avoid this in order to keep the setup as simple as possible for clients. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

You say "Clients should not have to create IAM roles". This is perfectly correct.

I presume that *you* are creating the instances for use by the clients. If so, then **you** should create an IAM Role that has access to the desired bucket.

Then, when you create an Amazon EC2 instance for your clients, associate the IAM Role to the instance. Your clients will then be able to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to access the S3 bucket (list, upload, download, or whatever permissions you put into the IAM Role).

If you want the data to be **automatically downloaded when you first create their instance**, then you can add **User Data script** that will execute when the instance starts. This can download the files from S3 to the instance.

Comment: This is a misunderstanding. Clients do actually create their own instances through AWS ParallelCluster. Thanks a lot for your quick answer though.

Comment: I edited my question to contain some more details about my use case. Initially, I wanted to have it more general because I thought this will apply not only to working with AWS Parallelcluster, but to EC2/S3 in general.

Comment: Are you saying that you already issue an Access Key and Secret Key to your clients? Or do they create instances "via" your application? If they actually do have their own IAM credentials, then simply add the bucket permissions to that IAM User.

Comment: They create instances "via" my application i.e. the use the AWS ParallelCluster CLI in combination with snapshot IDs and `post_install` scripts that I provide. However, I don't have access to their accounts or their instances.

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood! So clients have their own AWS account and you want to allow those particular accounts access to your S3 bucket? Do you also want to limit access so _only_ those accounts get access? If so, they will need to have Access Keys (or use Roles) so that AWS can recognize which account they are using. The alternative is to allow _anyone_ to access the bucket, or use your application to generate special URLs (but I'd need more info about what your app does to recommend this).

Comment: Yes, I would like to limit access to those accounts. Thank you for your time. I think I am aware of the options now, even though what I would like to have (Allowing access to a bucket for all client-created instances without any client-side configuration requirements) seems to be impossible.

Comment: Correct (sort of). If you want to grant access to "instances from a particular account", then the instances need to have credentials from that account to prove their authenticity. Otherwise, you'll have no way of know from which account the requests are being made.